# Game of Life .exe strange output

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I wrote a C code for a Game of Life simulation. My program works perfectly fine for case 1 which is my random array. But it doesn't work when I try to load an array out of a .txt file. I mean it gives me an output but it doesn't output an array with '*' or ' ' it gives me this:

[image: example of output]

Does someone know what my mistake is?

Here´s my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define ED 25   
#define ZD 25   

// - FUNCTIONS
void print_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m);
void create_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, int *alz, int prozent);
void check_neighbours(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, char lager[ED][ZD], int *alz);
void ausfuehren(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, char lager[ED][ZD], int *alz);
void load_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, int filenr, int *alz);
int Menu(char *text, int anz, char *prompt);
int check_rules(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, char lager[ED][ZD], int lx, int ly, int alz);
int Einlesen(char *prompt, int min, int max, int versuche);

// -MAIN-
int main() {
    const int n = ED; const int m = ZD;  //1.Dim/2.Dim
    char matr[ED][ZD]; 
    char lager[ED][ZD];
    int alz; //Anzahl lebender Zellen

    int prozent;
    switch (Menu("\n1 - random\n2 - load array 1\n3 - load array 2\n4 - load array 3\n\n0 - exit", 5, "\n >>>> ")) {
        case 0: exit(0); break;
        case 1:
            prozent = Einlesen("Percentage? ", 0, 100, 5);
            create_matr(matr, n, m, &alz, prozent); 
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            break;
        case 2: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 1,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 3: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 2,&alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz); break;
        case 4: 
            load_matr(matr, n, m, 3, &alz);
            print_matr(matr, n, m);
            ausfuehren(matr, n, m, lager, &alz);
            break;
        }
     return 0;
}
// -PRINT
void print_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m) {
    for (int lx = 0; lx < n; lx++) { 
        for (int ly = 0; ly < m; ly++) {
            printf(" %c", matr[lx][ly]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int Einlesen(char *prompt, int min, int max, int versuche) {
    int zahl;
    fflush(stdin);
    if (!versuche) {
        exit(0);
    }
    printf(prompt);
    if (!scanf("%d", &zahl)) {
        printf(" *** Bitte Zahl eingeben! ***\n");
        return Einlesen(prompt, min, max, versuche - 1);
    }
    if ((zahl<min) || (zahl>max)) {
        printf(" *** [%d,%d]! ***\n", min, max);
        return Einlesen(prompt, min, max, versuche - 1);
    }
    return zahl;
}

int Menu(char *text, int anz, char *prompt) {
    printf(text);
    return Einlesen(prompt, 0, anz, 5);
}

void create_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, int *alz, int prozent) {  
    for (int ln = 0; ln < n; ln++) {    
        for (int lm = 0; lm < m; lm++) {   
            if (rand()%100 <= prozent) {
                matr[ln][lm] = '*'; 
                (*alz)++;
            }
            else { matr[ln][lm] = ' ';}
        }
    }
}

int check_rules(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, char lager[ED][ZD], int lx, int ly, int l_anzlz) {
    //Rule 1
    if (matr[lx][ly] == '*') {
        if ((l_anzlz == 0) || (l_anzlz == 1) || (l_anzlz > 3)) {
            lager[lx][ly] = ' ';
        }
        //Rule 2
        else if ((l_anzlz == 2) || (l_anzlz == 3)) {
                lager[lx][ly] = '*';
        }
    }
    //Rule 3
    else if (matr[lx][ly] == ' ') {
        if (l_anzlz == 3) {
            lager[lx][ly] = '*';
        }
        else lager[lx][ly] = ' ';
    }
    return 1;
}

void check_neighbours(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, char lager[ED][ZD], int *alz) {
    int counteq = 0;
    int l_anzlz;
    (*alz)=0;
    for(int lx = 0; lx < n; lx++) { 
        for(int ly = 0; ly < m; ly++) { 
            l_anzlz = 0; 
            for(int la = -1; la <= 1; la++) { 
                for(int lb = -1; lb <= 1; lb++) { 
                    if((la==0)&&(lb==0)) continue; 
                    if((lx==0)&&(la==-1)) continue; 
                    if((lx==n-1)&&(la==1)) continue; 
                    if((ly==0)&&(lb==-1)) continue; 
                    if((ly==m-1)&&(lb==1)) continue; 

                    if (matr[lx + la][ly + lb] == '*') { 
                        l_anzlz++;
                    }
                }
            }
            check_rules(matr, n, m, lager, lx, ly, l_anzlz);
        }
    }
    //printf("lager\n");
    //print_matr(lager, n, m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (matr[i][j] == lager[i][j]) {
                counteq++;
            }
            matr[i][j] = lager[i][j];
            if (matr[i][j] == '*') (*alz)++;
        }
    }
    if (counteq == (n*m)) (*alz)=0;
}

// -EXECUTE
void ausfuehren(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, char lager[ED][ZD], int *alz) {
    char eing;
    int fors; 
    fors = Einlesen(" [0] or [1]?\n", 0, 1, 2);
    if(fors==1) printf(" 'q' to end \n");

    while ((*alz) > 0) {
        check_neighbours(matr, n, m, lager, alz); /
        print_matr(matr, n, m);
        if (fors == 0) {
            Sleep(300); 
        }
        else if (fors == 1) {
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &eing);
            if(eing=='q') break;
        }
    }
}


void load_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, int filenr, int *alz) {
    FILE *fp;
    char c[4];
    (*alz)=0;

    if (filenr == 1) {
        fp = fopen("matrix1.txt", "rt"); 
    }
    else if (filenr == 2) {
        fp = fopen("matrix2.txt", "rt");
    }
    else if (filenr == 3) {
        fp = fopen("matrix3.txt", "rt");
    }

    if(fp==0){
        printf("Couldnt open File!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(fgets(c, 5, fp)==NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    n=(int)(*c);
    if(fgets(c, 5, fp)==NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    m=(int)(*c);

    for (int lx = 0; lx < n; lx++) {
        for (int ly = 0; ly < m; ly++) {
            int star = fgetc(fp);
            if (star == 42) { //42=* | ASCII
                matr[lx][ly] = '*';
                (*alz)++;
            }
            else if (star == 32) { //32=  | ASCII
                matr[lx][ly] = ' ';
            }
            else if (star == 10) { //10=\n | ASCII
                lx--; ly = m - 1;

            }
            else break; //EOF
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Oups, it is rather long code... Could you try to strip it down to a [mcve]? Anyway, I suspect that program behaviour will depend on the content of matrix{1|2|3}.txt files but you did not show them...

Comment: Trace you loop in `load_matr` and montior what happens to your `lx` and `ly` variables.

Comment: @R.RiKo: then you should use a debugger or add *trace* `printf` statement to control that you have read what was expected. Without the files, I cannot do it for you.

Comment: `char c[4]; .... fgets(c, 5, fp)` why re you reading 5 bytes but only have storage for 4?

Comment: Instead of using ASCII codes for characters with comments describing what the codes mean, you could ... use `'`-enclosed character literals.

Comment: please post the contents of your input file.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do... while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).  3) use meaningful variable names, that indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both) 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: this statement: `fflush(stdin);` is explicitly declared as undefined behavior in the C standard.  The (shudder) Visual Studio allows it, along with a lot of other invalid actions.  (Note: `fflush()` is only for output streams, not input streams.)  Suggest: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: Note: `Sleep()` is not part of the standard C library functions and is therefore, not portable, Suggest using `nanosleep()`

Comment: regarding: `const int n = ED;` and `const int m = ZD;  //1.Dim/2.Dim`  The macros `ED` and `ZD` are already available, so why copy them to some local variables?

Comment: For ease of readability, consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `if (!scanf("%d", &zahl))`  The `scanf()` function can return EOF.  However, the posted codel treats that returned value as if the input/format were successful.  This is a significant logic error that needs correction.

Comment: regarding: `if (!scanf("%d", &zahl))
    {
        printf(" *** Bitte Zahl eingeben! ***\n");
        return Einlesen(prompt, min, max, versuche - 1);
    }`  Once the call to `scanf()` fails, calling it again will also fail.

Comment: regarding the `Einlesen()` function.  It would be MUCH better to use loops rather than recursive calls

Comment: regarding: `printf(text);`  this is a security vulnerability that you want to avoid.  Suggest: `printf( "%s", text);`

Comment: Why is `check_rules()`  returning an `int` when the only place that calls that function does not check the returned value?

Comment: regarding: `check_neighbours(matr, n, m, lager, alz); /`   Why is this line ended with a `line continuation` slash?

Comment: when calling `fopen()`,  the returned value should be checked for NULL, not 0.  And when the call fails, the error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` perhaps via calling: `perror( "Couldnt open File!" ); which will also output to `stderr`, the reason the system thinks the call failed.  similar considerations exist for a call to `fgets()`

Comment: regarding: `exit(-1);`  the header file: `stdlib.h`  has a definition for `EXIT_FAILURE` which is a more obvious name to use

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `if(fgets(c, 5, fp)==NULL){` this allows 3 digits max.  I.E. 000 ... 999.  Note that the original definitions for `matr[][]` only allocate room for `matr[25][25]`  however there is no check of the values read from the input file to assure they are 25 or less

Comment: regarding: `m=(int)(*c);`  this statement is almost assured to fail, For several different reasons.  Amongst them, `1` (0x31) is not the same thing as 1 ( 0x0)  Suggest using `strtol()` or `atoi()`

Comment: this kind of statement: `if (star == 42)`  would be much more clearly written as: `if (star == `*`)`

Comment: there are some other problems besides those referenced in the above comments, but the above should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is into the load_matr function:

This is a possible solution, that make it works when the input file is properly formatted (it is not a solution fault tolerant), and many bad things, but it works.

```
void clear_matr(char matr[ED][ZD])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < ED; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < ZD; col++)
            matr[row][col] = ' ';
}


void load_matr(char matr[ED][ZD], int n, int m, int filenr, int *alz) {
    FILE *fp;
    char c[16];
    (*alz)=0;
    memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));

    if (filenr == 1) {
        fp = fopen("matrix1.txt", "rt"); 
    }
    else if (filenr == 2) {
        fp = fopen("matrix2.txt", "rt");
    }
    else if (filenr == 3) {
        fp = fopen("matrix3.txt", "rt");
    }

    if (fp == 0) {
        printf("Couldnt open File!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (fgets(c, 5, fp) == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    n = atoi(c);

    if (fgets(c, 5, fp) == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    m = atoi(c);

    clear_matr(matr);

    for (int ly = 0; ly < m; ly++) {
        for (int lx = 0; lx < n; lx++) {
            int star = fgetc(fp);
            if (star == '\n')
                star = fgetc(fp);
            if (star == 42) { //42=* | ASCII
                matr[ly][lx] = '*';
                (*alz)++;
            }
            else if (star == 32) { //32=  | ASCII
                matr[ly][lx] = ' ';
            }
            else break; //EOF
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```